# Rigor in Banach contraction principle

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence

Given a contraction $T$ on $S$, we can after some triangle inequalities and so forth conclude that $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \{T^n(x)\}$ converges to some point $x^*$ in $S$.

I'm wondering: can't we stop at this point? What is the difference between stating convergence for this sequence to some point in $x^* \in S$ and stating that $x^*$ is a fixed point?

Comment: Consider $$f(x) = \begin{cases} \frac{x}{2} &, x \neq 0 \\ 1 &, x = 0.\end{cases}$$ $f^n(x) \to 0$ for all $x$, but $0$ is not a fixed point.

Comment: Usually we want the result to actually *be* a fixed point, for the application. You may get some insight by looking over the usual proof of the Picard-Lindelof theorem (from ODE) using Picard iteration.

Comment: Convergence isn't necessarily implied by having a contraction mapping, but if there is a point $y \in S$ such that $f^n(x)$ converges to $y$, then $f(y)$ must be $y$

Comment: @DanielFischer that isn't a contraction map btw, consider f(0) and f(1/2) for example

Comment: @muzzlator Naturally. If you have a contraction $T$ and $T^n(x) \to x^\ast$ for _some_ $x$, then $x^\ast$ is a fixed point of $T$. Well, if $T^n(x) \to x^\ast$, it suffices for $T$ to be continuous at $x^\ast$ to conclude that $x^\ast$ is a fixed point. So a "counterexample" must be discontinuous at $x^\ast$. It's just an illustration that you can't stop at $T^n(x) \to x^\ast$, you need to continue to show that $x^\ast$ is a fixed point.

Comment: @DanielFischer Contraction mappings are automatically continuous.  If there is such an $x^*$, it will be a fixed point

Comment: @muzzlator Yes, contractions are Lipschitz continuous. So for an illustration that one cannot stop short but must prove that $x^\ast$ is in fact a fixed point, one cannot use a contraction.

Comment: @DanielFischer Ok I think I've missed the point of OP's question :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, Banach contraction theorem says that every contraction (on a *complete* metric space) has a unique fixed point. So, once you know (in your notations) that the sequence $(T^n(x_0))_{n \in \mathbb N}$ converges to some $x^\star$ you have not concluded yet. You have just built a convergent sequence in your space (and you have done this by noticing that, chosen an arbitrary $x_0 \in X$ and set $x_{n+1} = T(x_n)$ for $n \ge 0$, the sequence $(x_n)_n$ is Cauchy, hence convergent since the space is complete).

You have to find a fixed point, so one has to observe that the limit of this sequence is indeed the fixed point we were looking for. And this trivially comes from the very definition $x_{n+1} = T^n(x_0) = T(x_n)$ so, passing to the limit in both sides and exploiting the (Lipschitz) continuity of $T$, we get $x^\star = T(x^\star)$.

Comment: Could you rephrase/expand on the first paragraph somehow? Not sure I grokk it 100%

Comment: Done, hope it is more clear now.

Comment: But it seems to me that continuity is trivially given by the contraction property. Is this not so?

Comment: Sure, (Lipschitz) continuity is given by contraction property (this is what I used in the last line).

Answer (score 0):

Not all fixed points can be reached by iterating.
Consider, for example the map $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$, $f(x)=2x$.
The only fixed point is the origin, what happens if you start iterating from another point?

The contraction property $|f(x)-f(y)|\leq c|x-y|$ for $c<1$ guarantees that every fixed point is actually contracting.
If $f(x)=x$, then $|x-f^n(y)|\leq c^n|x-y|$.

If the iterates $f^n(x)$ converge to $y$, then $y$ is a fixed point, provided that $f$ is continuous at $y$.
If this continuity condition fails, the claim can fail.
Consider $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ defined by $f(0)=1$ and $f(x)=x/2$ otherwise.

A key step in the proof of Banach's fixed point theorem can be stated in more generality: if $f:M\to M$ is a mapping in a metric space and $f$ is a contraction, then the iterates form a Cauchy sequence.
There is no guarantee, however, that a Cauchy sequence converges in general, whence the assumption of completeness.
Think about the function $f:M\to M$ for $M=[0,\frac12]\cap\mathbb Q$, $f(x)=x^2+1/5$.
It is a contraction and its iterates form a Cauchy sequence, but the limit never exists in $M$.